# classList.add( ) and classList.add( ) is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

So when users click the button, I want the first section to disappear, and the second section to show. What's happening here is like a flash. The first section just hides for a second, so does the second. Please take a look at code my code :)

HTML

```
 <style>
        .hide{
            display: none;
        }
 </style>


 <section id="first">
            <form>
                <label for="p1Name">PLAYER ONE</label>
                <input type="text" id="p1Name" placeholder="TYPE PLAYER NAME">
                <label class="label" for="p2Name">PLAYER TWO</label>
                <input type="text" id="p2Name" placeholder="TYPE PLAYER NAME">
                <button id="start">START</button>
            </form>
        </section>
        <section id="second" class="hide">
            <h1>HELLO, WORLD!!!</h1>
        </section>
```

Javascript

```
const button = document.querySelector("#start");
const firstPage = document.querySelector("#first");
const secondPage = document.querySelector("#second");

    button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        firstPage.classList.add("hide");
        secondPage.classList.remove("hide");
        console.log("work");       
    })
```

Comment: The default action for a `<button>` is to submit the form it is a child of. Either use the `submit` event of the form to change the visibility **and** stop that submission. Or change the type of the button to be "only" a button -> `type="button"`

Answer (score 1):

The default type of a button is *submit*, as a result the form is submitting when clicking the button. You can either explicitly set the type of the button to *button* or you can prevent the event inside the click event handler function using `preventDefault()` to stay on the page.

```js
const button = document.querySelector("#start");
const firstPage = document.querySelector("#first");
const secondPage = document.querySelector("#second");

button.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    firstPage.classList.add("hide");
    secondPage.classList.remove("hide");
    console.log("work");
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

```html
<style>
.hide{
    display: none;
}
</style>


<section id="first">
    <form>
        <label for="p1Name">PLAYER ONE</label>
        <input type="text" id="p1Name" placeholder="TYPE PLAYER NAME">
        <label class="label" for="p2Name">PLAYER TWO</label>
        <input type="text" id="p2Name" placeholder="TYPE PLAYER NAME">
        <button id="start">START</button>
    </form>
</section>
<section id="second" class="hide">
    <h1>HELLO, WORLD!!!</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: There are literaly thousands of (more or less good) duplicates...

Comment: Why is there text in the CSS section? Why is the `<style>` element in the HTML section?